# Storing the state of a VSTO Outlook plugin with a draft message

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm working on a VSTO plugin for Outlook (C#) and find nothing about saving or embedding the state/options of my plugin with a draft message.
Is there any mean to do that ?
Ex: if my plugin makes the message to be displayed in red, I want to have my draft re-opened written in red.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UserProperties.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.add) method which creates a new user property in the [UserProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties) collection. Use the `UserProperties` property to return the `UserProperties` object for an Outlook item. This applies to all Outlook items except for the `NoteItem`.

Use the `Add` method to create a new `UserProperty` for an item and add it to the `UserProperties` object. The `Add` method allows you to specify a name and type for the new property. When you create a new property, it can also be added as a custom field to the folder that contains the item (using the same name as the property) by setting the `AddToFolderFields` parameter to `true` when calling the `Add` method. That field can then be used as a column in folder views.

To set for the first time a property created by the `UserProperties.Add` method, use the `UserProperty.Value` property instead of the `SetProperties` and `SetProperty` methods of the `PropertyAccessor` object.

---

If you need to keep the data for the folder or Outlook account in general (not per item) you may consider the [StorageItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.storageitem) instead. That is a message object in MAPI that is always saved as a hidden item in the parent folder and stores private data for Outlook solutions.

The Outlook object model does not provide any collection object for `StorageItem` objects. However, you can use `Folder.GetTable` to obtain a `Table` with all the hidden items in a `Folder`, when you specify the `TableContents` parameter as `olHiddenItems`. If keeping your data private is of a high concern, you should encrypt the data before storing it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer :-)  I just added some UserProperty for an other functionnality of my plugin and told me these UserProperty were not saved and retrieved between 2 Outlook session :-( ... I give a try ...

Comment: You must call the `Save` to make changes saved to the store with a mail item.

Comment: Ok that was the next question :-) I'll try this next week (working 1 day per week on this project) ...

Comment: Hi back in ... Which Save method has to be called ? I tried the MailItem.Save and it creates a new message !

Comment: Where and when do you call the `Save` method? Sounds like a subject for another post, right?

Comment: Hi ... back on the subject ... the Save method is called just after the setting of the properties in the Application_ItemWrite callback

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene advised, you can use `MailItem.UserProperties` collection to set/read your custom properties.

A couple points to consider - since named properties are a finite resource, you can have at most 32k of them per mailbox. Once you go over, the mailbox is pretty much dead. So use as few unique properties as possible, and definitely do not use anything dynamic, such as the message subject in the property name.

If you set a user property on an outgoing message, Outlook might force it to go out in the TNEF format. To prevent that from happening, set the property value using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`. You can use the same DASL property name that your user property uses, but the point is to avoid using the `UserPropeties` collection. You can see the DASL property name in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select a message with your user property set, click IMessage button, select your property, see the DASL edit box.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ! I need 2 properties so it should be ok :-)